# How to squeeze space around these subequations?

Tags: equations, pdftex, align, subequations

I have two subequations as follows. I need to squeeze space before and after "and".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
        \Gamma_{CT} &=[\Gamma_{CT(1)},\ldots,\Gamma_{CT(i)}, \ldots \Gamma_{CT(n)}] \\
        & \text{where}, \ \Gamma_{CT(i)} = max (sim(i,1), \ldots, sim(i,m) \nonumber \\
        \intertext{and}
        \Gamma_{QT}&=[\Gamma_{QT(1)},\ldots,\Gamma_{QT(i)},\ldots,\Gamma_{QT(m)}] \\
        & \text{where}, \ \Gamma_{QT(j)} = max (sim(1,j), \ldots, sim(n,j) \nonumber
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: mathtools `\shortintertext`  but also `max` should be `\max` and declare an operator for `sim`  to use teh same font and spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done. even space not squeezed up.

Comment: please fix your example so that people can see the issue. (`\documentclass...\end{document}`)

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`). I also propose a different way to typeset the material.

Note: `sim` and `max` should be in upright type; `\max` is predefined for the purpose and I defined `\opsim` (because `\sim` is already taken).

Also there should be no need for `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\opsim}{sim}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{CT} ={}& [\Gamma_{CT(1)},\dots,\Gamma_{CT(i)},\dots,\Gamma_{CT(n)}] \\
               & \text{where } \Gamma_{CT(i)} = \max (\opsim(i,1),\dots,\opsim(i,m)) \notag
\shortintertext{and}
\Gamma_{QT} ={}& [\Gamma_{QT(1)},\dots,\Gamma_{QT(i)},\dots,\Gamma_{QT(m)}] \\
               & \text{where } \Gamma_{QT(j)} = \max (\opsim(1,j),\dots,\opsim(n,j)) \notag
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{CT} &= [\Gamma_{CT(1)},\dots,\Gamma_{CT(i)},\dots,\Gamma_{CT(n)}] \\
\Gamma_{QT} &= [\Gamma_{QT(1)},\dots,\Gamma_{QT(i)},\dots,\Gamma_{QT(m)}]
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where
\begin{align*}
\Gamma_{CT(i)} &= \max (\opsim(i,1),\dots,\opsim(i,m)) \\
\Gamma_{QT(j)} &= \max (\opsim(1,j),\dots,\opsim(n,j))
\end{align*}
\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]